# Designing a system to access JSON feeds from the backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in the process of rewriting some angular code as things are unclear and sparsely documented.

I have a number of data feeds which are returned as JSON.  So for example I have a products feed but also have other feeds such as weather and news etc.

I'm pretty new to angular so I want to check if what I'm thinking is good enough or can be improved.

I'm intending having a `factory` for each data feed so that they can be accessed multiple times throughout the app.  Any directives or controllers can then be associated with the the relevant module, so for the products feed I would have something like this:

```
    angular.module('products', [])

    .factory('products', function($http) {
      var products = {};
      products.get = function(params, callback) {
        $http.get('/php/products.php', {params: {page: params.page}}).success(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      };
      return products;
    });

    angular.module('app', ['products'])


    .controller('productsCtrl', function ($scope, products){
       $scope.page = 1;
       $scope.products=[];

        products.get({page: $scope.page}, function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.products.push(data[i]);
          }
        })
    });
```

This would mean that if I needed the products feed within a different controller I could do that easily.  For example I could have the last three products purchased in a different controller and just amend the params being passed back to the backend.

Comment: Instead of passing in a callback, you'll want to return the promise that `$http.get` returns.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind have a factory for these requests is a good one. You'll just want your function to return a promise instead of having to pass in a callback. Something like this:

```
    angular.module('products', [])

    .factory('products', function($http) {
      var products = {};
      products.get = function(params) {
        return $http.get('/php/products.php', {params: {page: params.page}});
      };
      return products;
    });

    angular.module('app', ['products'])


    .controller('productsCtrl', function ($scope, products){
       $scope.page = 1;
       $scope.products=[];

        products.get({page: $scope.page}).then(function (response) {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            $scope.products.push(data[i]);
          }
        }, function(errorResponse) {
           //any error handling
        })
    });
```

See the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more information on promises. Things get pretty messy passing callbacks around. Promises are the way go.

Comment: That does look better, might have to change this to be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks sufficient to me. If you have a more robust API to work with (perhaps w/ full CRUD) then [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) might be a better fit, but otherwise I think you're fine.